# Python random maths equation does not work

Tags: python, random

It doesn't tell you if the question is correct or not (when it should) and it doesn't do what it is supposed to when all of the questions have been asked. It should say this at the end: "You scored " + str(correctQuestions) + "/10 questions." 
Here is the code:

```
import random

name = input("What is your name: ")

finish = False
questionNumber = 0
correctQuestions = 0

while finish == False: 
    op = ['+','-','*']
    choice = random.choice(op)
    if questionNumber < 10 and questionNumber >= 0:
        number1 = random.randrange(1,10)
        number2 = random.randrange(1,10)
        print((number1),(choice),(number2))
        answer=int(input("What is the answer?"))
        questionNumber = questionNumber + 1

if choice==("+"):
    realAnswer = number1+number2
elif answer==realAnswer:
    print("That's the correct answer")
    correctQuestions = correctQuestions + 1
else:
    print("Wrong answer")

if choice==("*"):
    realAnswer = number1*number2
elif answer==realAnswer:
    print("That's the correct answer")
    correctQuestions = correctQuestions + 1
else:
    print("Wrong answer")

if choice==("-"):
    realAnswer = number1-number2
elif answer==realAnswer:
    print("That's the correct answer")
    correctQuestions = correctQuestions + 1
else:
    print("Wrong answer")

if finish == True:
    print("You scored " + str(correctQuestions) + "/10 questions.")
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl It looks like THE HOMEWORK question, may I propose the new tag `the-math-quiz-in-python`?

Answer (score 0):

As this looks like a homework exercise i will not solve it for you take some time and think about it. However here are some hints:

The variable `finish` is always `False`, it never gets updated, so its no wonder the game is never finished. Do something about that.

Second at line `if choice==("+"):` it can be possible that the variable `choice` does not exist (nor `number1` and `number2`). Think about what you put under the `while` loop and what you don't.

Also there is a variable `realAnswer` in an `elif` statement while you did not declared it before. As the variable does not even exist, it will give you a `NameError` if it gets evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `choice` is `*`.  Python gets to `if choice==("+"):`.  The result: False, so it checks the `elif`: `elif answer==realAnswer:`  At this point `realAnswer` has not yet been defined.  You define `realAnswer` in the `if` block, but the `if` block did not execute.  You need to take out the `elif` and `else` blocks from each `choice`, and instead put them at the end:

```
if answer == realAnswer:
    print("That's the correct answer")
    correctQuestions = correctQuestions + 1
else:
    print("Wrong answer")
```

Also, you never define `finish` as anything but `False`.  You use `if questionNumber < 10 and questionNumber >= 0:`, but you don't say what to do if `questionNumber` is *not* between `0` and `10`.  You need an `else` block that will break out of the loop.